# Resolve a dependacy fail with libc-bin on debian

Tags: debian, packages

I had a very old server on etch and i tried to upgrade it to jessie.

everything was good until wheezy

when i made dist-upgrade, it try to upgrade libc6

```
WARNING: this version of the GNU libc requires kernel version
2.6.26 or later. Please upgrade your kernel before installing
glibc.

The installation of a 2.6 kernel _could_ ask you to install a new libc
first, this is NOT a bug, and should *NOT* be reported. In that case,
please add lenny sources to your /etc/apt/sources.list and run:
  apt-get install -t lenny linux-image-2.6
```

before that message, it already installs libc-bin

so that command cannot work but I downloaded it on https://archive.debian.net/squeeze/i386/linux-image-2.6.32-5-686/download

and installed it with dpkg, I had that message :

```
Pr▒paration du remplacement de linux-image-2.6.32-5-686 2.6.32-48squeeze6 (en utilisant linux-image-2.6.32-5-686_2.6.32-48squeeze6_i386.deb) ...
D▒paquetage de la mise ▒ jour de linux-image-2.6.32-5-686 ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 2.6.32-5-686 /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-5-686
Param▒trage de linux-image-2.6.32-5-686 (2.6.32-48squeeze6) ...
Running depmod.
aptRunning update-initramfs.
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-5-686
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 2.6.32-5-686 /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-5-686
```

so I think it was installed, but I still have a conflict with libc6 (dependancy unmet)

```
Les paquets suivants contiennent des d▒pendances non satisfaites▒:
 libc6 : D▒pend: libc-bin (= 2.11.3-4) mais 2.13-38+deb7u11 est install▒
 locales : D▒pend: glibc-2.13-1
```

so I don't know what to do :

- I can reboot linux on the new kernel), but I don't know how the old libc6 will work with the new libc-bin
- I can try to reinstall libc-bin on the old version but I don't know how to do safely

Can someone help me ? That's a mess

Comment: Did you do the upgrade step-by-step, i.e. from Etch to Lenny, then from Lenny to Squeeze and then to Wheezy? Skipping intermediate versions is not supported in upgrades. You will need to install a fresh version of kernel in each step as well to avoid problems. You might try to run `apt -f install` to sort out problems that can be sorted out automatically.

Comment: yes i made it step by step apt-get -f install give : 
 libc6 : Depend: libc-bin (= 2.11.3-4) mais 2.13-38+deb7u11 est installe
 locales : Depend: glibc-2.13-1

Comment: I tryied to make dpkg -i --force-all libc6_2.13-38+deb7u11_i386.deb but I have the same warning, I fear to reboot. WARNING: this version of the GNU libc requires kernel version 2.6.26 or later. Please upgrade your kernel before installing glibc.

Comment: What version of libc6 do you have installed? 2.13-38? Or did you cancel the upgrade? In any case, make sure the new and old kernel are included in your grub boot list (this should have happened automatically when installing the kernel, but check their presence in /boot/grub/grub.cfg). Then you should be able to boot the machine up with either the new or old kernel.

Comment: well i understand now what was the problem. I use a vm with the provider gandi. it is a network kernel and I didn't know it. so when i upgraded, debian should be a specific version of linux kernel but it wasn't. btw i corrected the problem with a configuration of the good kernel, a reboot and some apt-get command. tk you